# Connecting to Heroku DB via Android APP with play on server side

Tags: database, heroku, playframework-2.2

I am new to Heroku and playframework.
trying to create a project where i can update and read DB via android / ios app i am developing.

I would like to create some sort of service using play framework that when requested by android/ios app will update db (security here is important).

how do i create such service ? if answer is to complex is there a tutorial i can be flowered to ? 
appreciate the help.

EDIT:

I realize my question might be general/unfocused (due to my own lack of knowledge).
i will try to elaborate.
my purpose is to build an app for my kids kindergarten where the caretakers can update messages to parents in the website interface and the application will read these messages from  the data base. i understand it is not recommended that an application read directly from DB but use a service. as my web site is built with playframework and hosted on heroku i was wondering how do i get this all to connect ?

Comment: The -1 is a little depressing, as  a new user without knowledge i understand questions can be unfocused. i believe the correct approach should be to refer me to a beginner tutorial, or at least point out what is wrong in comment,  not to demote and walk away with out any explanation.

Comment: The -1 wasn't me, and I am happy you want to learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions on SO. As it pertains to your question as currently written, I feel like it is not specific. I don't know anything about heroku, and I barely know how to pronounce "Android", but what I do know is that we love [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) here on SO. Hopefully, your future questions will be a more pleasant experience for both you and us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's hard to guess what are you asking about...

I'd suggest to build JSON API with Play application [which handles JSON requests](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests), from your mobile apps. Quite simple case, however you ned to put some effort for planning.

Although we don't know much about your approach, most probably [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) signature for  authentication will be good enough for this kind of job.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, as i am new to this world. i guess im not really sure what/how to ask. would be glad to elaborate..  just point me to the unclear sides.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid, that first you need to get in general touch with Play, and then ask for concrete things. We would need to elaborate you half of official documentation instead :/

Comment: Went over JSON request link, it was exactly what i needed. thank you.